# How to show top 10 most frequent tags in Grafana, using InfluxDB as data source

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxql

I am trying to show top 10 most frequent tags in Grafana, but I can't make it. The schema of my measurement (which is called `mymeasurement`) in InfluxDB is as follows:

```
timestamp | value | mytag
-------------------------
time_1    | 1     | tag_1
-------------------------
time_2    | 1     | tag_2
-------------------------
time_3    | 1     | tag_1
-------------------------
time_4    | 1     | tag_3
-------------------------
time_5    | 1     | tag_2
```

where `value` is the field in InfluxDB, and `mytag` is the tag.

Now, I can show all the tags with times of their appearance using the following query in Grafana:

```sql
SELECT count(value) FROM mymeasurement WHERE time > now() - 1h GROUP BY mytag
```

But when the measurement get larger and larger (with more and more tags), Bar Gauge in Grafana shows all the tags, which gets annoying over time. I tried to use this query to get top 10 tags:

```sql
SELECT top(mycount, mytag, 10) FROM (SELECT count(value) AS mycount FROM mymeasurement WHERE time > now() - 1h GROUP BY mytag)
```

It looked great in the command line `influx` tool, but in Grafana it shows two meaningless bars. How should I address this problem?

Comment: In Grafana 7.2 there is a Transform tab next to Query tab. Can it be used to solve this problem?